# Modal com registro carregados do banco para edição usando PDO

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Como trazer registo do banco diretamente dentro de um modal usando o PDO?
Cadastrar registo usando um modal eu consigo, só q nao consigo fazer a edição.
No modo normal os registro vem de boa mas quando clico no botao EDITAR para trazer a janela com os registro nada acontece!

Embaixo segue o codigo.

HTML

```
<a href="modalLogin.php?update&id=<?php echo $rs->alun_id;?>"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >Edite</a>
```

JavaScript e PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['atualizar'])) {
    $id = (INT) $_GET['id'];
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];

    $pgUpdate = 'UPDATE alunos SET alun_nome=:nome   WHERE alun_id=:id';

    $update = $db->prepare($pgUpdate);
    $update->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $update->bindValue(':nome', $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $update->execute();

    header("location: alunList.php");
}

//buscando dados preenchido para dentro do formulario        
if (isset($_GET['update'])) {

    $id = (int) $_GET['id'];
    $pgSelect = 'SELECT * FROM alunos where alun_id = :id';

    $select = $db->prepare($pgSelect);
    $select->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $select->execute();

    $result = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    ?>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Login</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
                        <form role="form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nome"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Username</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" value="<?= $result->alun_nome; ?>">
                            </div>


                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Salvar</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
<?php } ?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myBtn").click(function () {
            $("#myModal2").modal();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Olhe [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80035/passar-varialvel-para-modal).